# javascript object recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, yui

Hi all i have the following function inside an yui object :

```
fun1: function (x){
    ....
    if (condition)
        this.fun1(x-1);
}
```

but I've seen in debug mode that the instruction `this.fun1(x-1)` raise the error:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
How can solve it ?

Comment: It is not quite clear from the concise snippet you have provided what `this` is bound to in the `if` condition. Are you 100% sure it points to the very same object you belive `fun1` is defined in?

Comment: `this` is defined at _invocation time_, you'll need to look where `fun1` is invoked for the first time if you want to know the value of `this`

Comment: Please provide the entire code, including the definition of the object inside which `fun1` is defined, and how it is called.

Answer (score 2):

in object literal notation that you used to define object, avoid using this because this refers to window object. Instead you can used object name of which you are creating property like.

```
var obj = {
   testfunction: function() {
        obj.testfunction();
   }
};
```

Comment: It's not the case that `this` will be `window` because it's in an property of an _Object literal_, `var foo = {bar: function () {return this;}}; foo.bar() === foo; // true`

Comment: This is a horrible idea, because it ties the behavior of `testfunction` to the specific object it is defined as part of.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to ensure you calling the right function is not to depend on this and not to use anonymous function. Give you function a temporary name and call it like this.

```
var obj ={
fun : function Q(a){
    if(a>0){
        return Q(a-1) + a;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

It is a common practice to call it with one capital letter if you will only call it by this name for recursion.

Try and always give your functions a name as it is easier to debug this way (function name will appear in call trace)

Please note that using recursion in javascript can be dangerous as javascript doesn't have tail-call optimization and you can run to stack overflow easily if you're not carefull.

Comment: This idea will fail if `Q` makes references to other properties of the object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For this reason you name it by convention with single capital letter.

Comment: I don't understand what naming, whether single lettered or capitalized, has to do with anything. My issue is, let's say the `Q` function refers to `this.val`. Your call to `Q(a-1)` passes along no `this`, so the reference to `this.val` in the invoked function will fail. You would need to do `Q.call(this, a-1)` to ensure this does not happen. But if you are going to use `this`, you might as well use `this.fun(a-1)`. Now we're back to the OP's original question, and why it didn't work, and you answer is...what?

Comment: Sorry i din't understand your comment, now its clear. You absolutely right it will not help if you referencing another properties of the object but i dont think it was the original question.